# How to get spinner selected item's line number?

Tags: java, android, mysql, spinner

I have to get the line number on the item selected in my spinner when i click on the save button. i need the line number not the text.

`uni = universite.getSelectedItem().toString();`

this code is selecting text. I am saving id in my database. so i need the line number.

Comment: Does this relate to PHP (except for where you pass the data onto)?

Comment: I pass the data to phpmyadmin. codes java code for android

Comment: phpmyadmin is just a tool to manage MySQL.

Comment: yes I know. I'm saving the data on mysql. the result i want is in above java codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this, it will give your the position of selected item

```
universite.getSelectedItemPosition()
```

Comment: How do I equate it to String value? I will pass the value to the database as a string

Comment: You can use String.valueOf(universite.getSelectedItemPosition()); Like this